# jove: ..../anaconda3/bin/../lib/libtinfo.so.6: no version information available (required by jove)

Tags: anaconda, conda, conda-forge

I install jove in conda base environment

```
conda install conda-forge::jove
```

The channel information:

```
Channels:                                                                                                                                                 
 - defaults                                                                                                                                               
 - conda-forge 
Platform: linux-64
```

But after I finished install, every time when I open the jove editor the error message appears:

```
jove: ..../anaconda3/bin/../lib/libtinfo.so.6: no version information available (required by jove)
```

How could I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The channel order is incorrect. Conda Forge only links against other Conda Forge packages, so if you need a *compiled* Conda Forge package, then all other libraries in the environment should come from Conda Forge. In this case, `conda-forge::jove` expects the `conda-forge::ncurses` package to be installed, which provides the `lib/libtinfo.so` file(s).<sup>**1**</sup>

Otherwise, one is prone to such library loading or feature mismatch issues (see [*"Using multiple channels"*](https://conda-forge.org/docs/user/tipsandtricks.html#using-multiple-channels)). It should also be noted that Anaconda **base** really does not *in practice* support the prioritization of `conda-forge` channel - one must create a new environment.

Try creating a new environment that prioritizes `conda-forge` over `defaults`:

```bash
conda create -n foo -c conda-forge jove
```

Even better, use YAML to define your environment:

**foo.yaml**

```yaml
name: foo
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - nodefaults  # do not search other channels
dependencies:
  - jove
  # list other packages you need
```

```bash
conda env create -n foo -f foo.yaml
```

---

<sub>**[1]:** One can inspect the provenance of file using the `conda package --which` command. In this case, `conda package --which $CONDA_PREFIX/lib/libtinfo.so.6` will reveal what package this file came from including the channel. When I sourced `ncurses` from `defaults`, I received the same error as OP reports; changing it to `conda-forge` was sufficient to resolve it. However, it is best practice to avoid mixing `defaults` and `conda-forge` channels altogether.</sub>